# JS - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Why am I getting this error?

```
  <ul>
        <%for(i=0;i<=todolist.length;i++){%>
        <li><%=todolist[i].name%></li>
        <% }%>
      </ul>
```

Comment: There is no property `name` used in code shown

Comment: Include more details

Comment: Typo: `i<=todolist.length` should be `i < todolist.length`. As you have no element with index `todolist.length` in `todolist`.

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Can you just console.log todolist?

Comment: This error message is telling you that some element of `todolist` that you are trying to access is `undefined` and does not contain an object like your code assumes.   Therefore, when you attempt to access `todolist[i].name`, you get an error because `todolist[i]` is not an object for that element. YOU will have to examine what is in todolist to figure out why that is.  This assumes you already changes to `i < todolist.length` because your previous code would have ben attempting access off the end of the array.

Comment: [
  { _id: 5fa6a7b1cba7ba315476f989, name: 'haziq', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5fa6a7bdcba7ba315476f98a, name: 'wahaj', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5fa6a94dcba7ba315476f98b, name: 'aziz', __v: 0 }  
]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like EJS.  Maybe from the server try something like this:

```
var template_file_path = "???";    

require ("ejs").renderFile (template_file_path, {
    todolist: [{
        name: "A"
    },{
        name: "B"
    }]
}, {}, function (err, strand) {
    if (err) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.end ();
        return;
    }

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.write (strand);
    res.end ();
});
```

If it's not EJS.. then i have no idea.